# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
def fx(x):
    v = float(x*x*x - 5*x - 7)
    return v


err = int(input("Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: "))
b = float(input("Enter upper limit for root: "))
a = float(input("Enter lower limit for root: "))
c = 0.0
while fx(c) > (1 * 10 ** -err):
    c = b - ((b - a)/(fx(b) - fx(a))) * fx(b)
    print(a, b, c, sep=', ')
    a = b
    b = c
    # c = 0
    print()
print("The root is approximately = ", b)
```

Why am I getting a zero division error on executing this code even though the loop gives the correct values in spite of the error?

Edit: I changed the ^ operator to ** and removed the c = 0 but now the answer is not even close to the actual answer. ^ operator was giving me the correct answer strangely.

Output with ** operator:

```
Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: 3
Enter upper limit for root: 2
Enter lower limit for root: 1
The root is approximately =  2.0
```

Output with ^ operator:

```
Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: 3
Enter upper limit for root: 2
Enter lower limit for root: 1
1.0, 2.0, 6.5
Traceback (most recent call last):

2.0, 6.5, 2.1658986175115205
  File "C:/Users/anves/PycharmProjects/nt/nt.py", line 46, in <module>

    c = b - (((b - a)/(fx(b) - fx(a))) * fx(b))
6.5, 2.1658986175115205, 2.302797651275858

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
2.1658986175115205, 2.302797651275858, 2.934211734811194

2.302797651275858, 2.934211734811194, 2.705017710718186

2.934211734811194, 2.705017710718186, 2.7438299655247143

2.705017710718186, 2.7438299655247143, 2.7474171932954787

2.7438299655247143, 2.7474171932954787, 2.7473464241055843

2.7474171932954787, 2.7473464241055843, 2.7473465403033757

2.7473464241055843, 2.7473465403033757, 2.747346540307211

2.7473465403033757, 2.747346540307211, 2.747346540307211
```

The last value is the correct value which is not getting printed?

Comment: The power operator in Python is `**`, not `^`.

Comment: Thierry is right. The `^` operator is a bitwise-xor operation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am not getting the answer at all if I use the ** operator

Comment: You set `c` to 0 at the end of your for loop. Meaning your while statement is checking if `fx(0) > error_bound` EVERY time. If it's true once, it will be true forever.

Comment: You have an infinite loop

Comment: You should test `abs(fx(c)) > (1 * 10 ** (-err))`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am testing the code from an example in my textbook

Comment: @SyntaxVoid I did your change, the answer didnt change

Comment: The reason you get an output when you use the `^` operator is because you don't even *enter* your while loop. Notice that the answer you get is *always* whatever you put in for `b`.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid it does enter the while loop, try running the code in pycharm

Comment: You can watch the values become the same and exit in the event that `a == b` ([live example](https://repl.it/@ryanhaining/SmoggyGloriousComments)).  As an aside, it looks like you are coming to programming from a math background. One of the best ways to make this transition is to use better names than `a`, `b`, `c`, or `fx`. Your code will be a lot easier to digest if others can understand the significance of your variables and functions by their names.

Comment: @RyanHaining I have to use variable names like a,b,c since I cant use x0, x1, x2, x3, and so on or else I'll have to create new variables for every loop which could run hundreds of times

Comment: I am not saying use `x0` either, that's not any better. You can name your variables whatever you would like, but if `b` is supposed to be the upper limit, just call it `upper_limit` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add the suggestions of using `abs()` and `**` and then catch the exception I get code like this:

```
def fx(x):
    v = float(x*x*x - 5*x - 7)
    return v


err = int(input("Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: "))
b = float(input("Enter upper limit for root: "))
a = float(input("Enter lower limit for root: "))
c = 0.0

while abs(fx(c)) > ( 10 ** -err):
    try:
        c = b - ((b - a)/(fx(b) - fx(a))) * fx(b)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        break
    print(a, b, c, sep=', ')
    a = b
    b = c
    c = 0
    print()
print("The root is approximately = ", b)
```

When I run it I get this:

```
Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: 3
Enter upper limit for root: 2
Enter lower limit for root: 1
1.0, 2.0, 6.5

2.0, 6.5, 2.1658986175115205

6.5, 2.1658986175115205, 2.302797651275858

( steps omitted )

2.7473464241055843, 2.7473465403033757, 2.747346540307211

2.7473465403033757, 2.747346540307211, 2.747346540307211

The root is approximately =  2.747346540307211
```

Does this produce the right answer?

You can see from the penultimate line of output where the last two numbers are identical (b and c) that the next time round the loop a and b will have these values and so `fx(b) - fx(a)` will result in `0.0` and a ZeroDivisionError.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code, and found that `fx(b)` and `fx(a)` are the same value. So when you calculate `fx(b)` minus `fx(a)` you get `0`
Hope this helps.

```
Terminal -----------------------------------
Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: 5
Enter upper limit for root: 5
Enter lower limit for root: 5
93.0
93.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/PythonScripts/first_python_project/curso_python.py", line 13, in <module>
    c = b - ((b - a)/(fx(b) - fx(a))) * fx(b)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Adding some more:
When you reach lower values, just `fx(b)` and `fx(a)` turn pretty similar.
Something like this:

```
Enter zeroes in approxiamtion in solution: 3
Enter upper limit for root: 5
Enter lower limit for root: 3
93.0
5.0
3.0, 5.0, 2.8863636363636362

2.614751596543952
93.0
5.0, 2.8863636363636362, 2.825218326106125

1.424401534793665
2.614751596543952
2.8863636363636362, 2.825218326106125, 2.7520503761266304

0.08317571970829363
1.424401534793665
2.825218326106125, 2.7520503761266304, 2.747512887487003

0.002935214303143141
0.08317571970829363
2.7520503761266304, 2.747512887487003, 2.747346905212986

6.43830337132556e-06
0.002935214303143141
2.747512887487003, 2.747346905212986, 2.747346540335565

5.002736003234531e-10
6.43830337132556e-06
2.747346905212986, 2.747346540335565, 2.747346540307211

1.7763568394002505e-15
5.002736003234531e-10
2.747346540335565, 2.747346540307211, 2.747346540307211

1.7763568394002505e-15
1.7763568394002505e-15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/PythonScripts/first_python_project/curso_python.py", line 13, in <module>
    c = b - ((b - a)/(fx(b) - fx(a))) * fx(b)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Well you made the upper and lower limits the same, of course you will get a zero division error.

Comment: upper limit should be greater than lower limit

Comment: `"and found that fx(b) and fx(a) are the same value"`  **you** inputted the same value for `a` and `b`, of course `fx(b) - fx(a)` will be 0

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Yep, a little thing that this code does not take into account.

Comment: @TomásPrudente I am not making an elaborate code, this is just a test code I made to check the formula

Comment: Oh, so your problem could be the second case. I suggest to put an exit triggered by the difference between `fx(b)` and `fx(a)` (when it's lower than xx value, finish). What do you think? @MUSTANGBOSS8055

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because at some point in your code

lets say `fx(a)=1.0000000000000001`  and `fy(b)=1.0`

and instead of `fx(a)-fy(b)=0.0000000000000001` you are getting 0.0 .

so zero division error is coming beacuse of this

Comment: What solution do you propose to combat this

Comment: i suggest you increase precision point or add try and except condition to tackle this

Comment: Then shouldn't that be your **answer**?

Comment: @SyntaxVoid op has asked for why , i tell him why, in comment he asked how to tacle which i answer as well

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems. 
One is with the expression **(1 * 10 ^ -err)**. Operator **^** in Python means bitwise  XOR and 10 ^ -err is a negative integer. So your loop does not end eevn after the root was found.
It should be **(10 ** -err)**. Also you have to compare abs(f(c)) with it.

Second problem is with c = 0 as initial value for the root. It should be within (a, b) interval, not zero.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rework your logic, but I can tell you that `(1 * 10 ** -err)` does not do what you think it does. `^` is a bitwise exclusive or operator. For exponents, you need `**`. So your code should be

```
(1 * 10 ** -err)
```

I tried running it, and it immediately stops due to fx(0) being a negative number, which is less than the very small positive value generated in the parentheses above.

Here's a working version, although I'm not sure what the code actually accomplishes...

```
def fx(x):
    v = float(x*x*x - 5*x - 7)
    return v


err = int(input("Enter zeroes in approximation in solution: "))
b = float(input("Enter upper limit for root: "))
a = float(input("Enter lower limit for root: "))
c = 0.0
ctr = 0 #                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
while abs(fx(c)) > (1 * 10 ** -err) and fx(b) != fx(a): # ^ is binary xor!
    ctr += 1
    c = b - ((b - a)/(fx(b) - fx(a))) * fx(b)
    print(ctr, a, b, c, sep=', ')
    a = b
    b = c
    c = 0
    print()
print("The root is approximately = ", b, ' after ', ctr, ' iterations')
input()
```

I tried running this three times, with range 1 to 10 and 1/3/8 zeroes. All three times the result ended up with b exactly the same. It just took a different number of iterations to get there.